# Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the normal metric (d(x,y)=|x-y|). Exist an open cover of $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} $ that haven't a finite subcover?

Tags: analysis

I don't think so, this is my argument:
$[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} $ isn't closed, so it can't be compact. But I don't found an example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $i\in [0,1]$ be an irrational number. The covering 
$$\{([0,1]\cap\Bbb Q)\setminus [i-\frac{1}{n}, i+\frac{1}{n}]:\,\,i\in\Bbb n\}$$ has no finite subcovering.

Comment: Yes of course :). But are they open?

Comment: Yes, they are open. Each element of such set has distance from $i$ strictly larger then $\frac{1}{n}$ so the same is true for some neighborhood.

Comment: But in an interval there are only elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, I don't understand how that can be open? If you take an element in such an interval, there are always irrational numbers near that point.

Comment: Open in the metric that you described, of course. Everything lives in $\Bbb Q$. (The sets of the covering in my answer above are subsets of $\Bbb Q$ and open subsets of $\Bbb Q$ are such that they contain a neighborhood (in $\Bbb Q$) with each element.)